# Nexus 6P stuck in charge mode when plugged in to my computer

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, nexus

I was developping android apps like many times on my Nexus 6P, but since few days my phone isn't detected on my PC. 
I Googled it but I didn't find any solutions !

More about my problem : 
I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my computer and Android Nougat 7.1.2 N2G47O on my Nexus 6P.

I have Android Studio 2.3, SDK updated and adb installed.
I have Developer Mode and USB Debugging switched on.

When I plug my phone to computer, I don't get the "Debugging" and "Connected to computer" notifications.

I tried to connect another phone to my pc (Samsung Galaxy Y) and everything worked perfectly.

Maybe I forget to do something on my phone ?
Hope you can help me ! 
Thanks :)

[image: MTP mode is on]

Comment: It's something with the android 7.1 on ubuntu and it's very annoying.

Comment: Do you have a solution maybe ?

Answer (score -1):

I remember having some issues on Linux with this device.

First check that the option "USB debugging" in the section "Debugging" is on.
Then on your udev rules (/etc/udev/rules.d/) add these two rules :

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6",  MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

The first one is for Qualcom vendor and the second one for Google. I know it is weird but if you do an lsusb, you will see that this device is sometimes detected as being a Qualcom device.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying me ! My 51-android.rules file already have theses rules in it ...